# Gmail IMAP via php ouath2 Zend_Mail_Protocol_Imap - getting the X-GM-THRID

Tags: gmail, imap, zend-mail

I'm accessing GMail via IMAP using OAuth2 authentication and `Zend_Mail_Protocol_Imap`.

It all works great.

What I need to do is present emails in thread form just like the GMail interface.  Google make this really easy because they have an `X-GM-THRID` header that links a conversation with a 64-bit unsigned integer.

My problem is: when presented with a single email, how do I find out what `X-GM-THRID` it belongs to?

First off Google says that there is a server extension `X-GM-EXT-1` which is active. You can check it is there using the `CAPABILITY` command (and I have).

All the information suggests that if this is active then the `X-GM-THRID` will simply be returned as a header, but it isn't.

Perhaps I need to ask Google to return it via the fetch command.  Google does describe a simple fetch process here:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/imap_extensions

My code is sending `TAG5 FETCH 3673 (FLAGS RFC822.HEADER X-GM-THRID)` but the headers do not include an entry for `X-GM-THRID`.

I've even simplified it to `TAG6 FETCH 3673 (X-GM-THRID)` to be exactly as described in the google example.  In this case no headers are returned.

I'm not massively familiar with `IMAP` commands and I'm not sure if `Zend_Mail_Protocol_Imap` is abstracting some handling which means this header is being removed.

But I do know that this is driving me mad.

Am I missing something?  Is it not a header?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so it looks like it is not a header.  It is an attribute in the IMAP command and response.

The standard fetch command sent by Zend_Mail_Protocol_Imap  is "TAG5 FETCH 3673 (FLAGS RFC822.HEADER)"

The code that handles the response only expects to be dealing with 'FLAGS' and 'RFC822.HEADER'.  It passes this information to a Zend_Mail_Message object which extends Zend_Mail_Part.

Zend_Mail_Part parses information about flag.  It also parses the header.

The additional 'X-GM-THRID' attribute that I added does actually get a response.  but since it is not passed back to Zend_Mail_Message there is no way for me to use it.  It gets lost in the ether (at around line 171 of Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap in my Zend Library to be exact).

So I've hacked the core... Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap::getMessage now expects $data['X-GM-THRID'] and passes it to the constructor Zend_Mail_Part.  And I now have a method Zend_Mail_Part::getXGmThrid which solves all my problems.  I'll obviously refactor them into my own classes extending Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap and Zend_Mail_Part in the not too distant... but for now I know this works.